# Validations for url field

Tags: javascript, html, url

I have input text in my webapplication which is used for entering url for his site by different users.What validations, i should have for that field.
I want to know following information :-
1. What characters I should allow user to enter.
2. Which character i should restrict.

We are just saving this url in database.
Please note , this data will be used by some other application as url, which is not using url encoding and I don't have access to code of that application. Only thing , I can do is not allowing users such character.

I am using jquery and javascript for client side validations

Comment: please have a look at this jquery plugin `http://jqueryvalidation.org/`

Comment: Try this http://jqueryvalidation.org/url-method/

Comment: Kindly add the comments while downvoting my question , so that i can improve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this  - http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/url

No need to write and verify the regex yourself

```
 $("#yourForm").validate({
    rules: {
      field: {
        required: true,
        url: true
      }
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Instructions:

1. Match for protocol (optional) and domain
2. Match protocol, allow in format http:// or mailto:
3. Allow something@ for email addresses
4. Anything looking at all like a domain, non-unicode domains
5. Starting with something@ or www.
6. Anything looking at all like a domain
7. Match for path, query string and anchor
8. Allow optional /path
9. Allow optional query string starting with ?
10. Allow optional anchor #anchor
11. Make URL suffix optional

You can use the regex from the following code:

```
var message;
var myRegExp =/^(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/[^\s]*)?$/i;

var urlToValidate = "http://www.google.com";
    if (!myRegExp.test(urlToValidate)){
    message = "Not a valid URL.";
    }else{
    message =  "Its a valid URL."
    }
    alert(message);
```

Source: http://blog.roymj.co.in/url-validation-using-regular-expression-javascript/

**EDIT**

JQuery Validation does more than what is required. If URL Validation is the only thing required then this is the regex used by JQuery Validation for URLs:

```
/^(https?|ftp):\/\/(((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)*@)?(((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?)(:\d*)?)(\/((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)?(\?((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\/|\?)*)?(\#((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|\/|\?)*)?$/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can match your string against a **Regex** to check if is valid:

Here is a pattern which validates a valid URL:

```
/^(https?|ftp:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/
```

**How to use it**:

```
var url = 'http://google.com',
urlRegex = /^(https?|ftp:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/;

console.log(urlRegex.test(url));
```

Comment: this will fail for URLs with other protocols like "ftp" etc.